# Optimizing Geo Search Query

Tags: mysql, database, performance, mariadb

I am currently storing users location in user_geo_places table. 
I store all their latest location including their past locations.

Common task I need,

- query only the lastest location by category
- query nearby users on location specified
- order results by distance
- get distance for each result base on location specified

The table

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| id         | varchar(36)   | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| user_id    | varchar(36)   | NO   | MUL | NULL                |       |
| deleted_at | timestamp     | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| created_at | timestamp     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| updated_at | timestamp     | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| latitude   | double(25,20) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |       |
| longitude  | double(25,20) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |       |
| category   | varchar(36)   | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| status     | int(11)       | YES  |     | 1                   |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

This is my index

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| user_geo_places |          1 | latitude   |            1 | latitude    | A         |     1894347 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| user_geo_places |          1 | longitude  |            1 | longitude   | A         |     1894347 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| user_geo_places |          1 | updated_at |            1 | updated_at  | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| user_geo_places |          1 | user_id    |            1 | user_id     | A         |     1894347 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Getting the latest location for each users

```
Select  user_geo_places.*
    from  user_geo_places
    left join  user_geo_places b
               ON (user_geo_places.user_id = b.user_id
              and  user_geo_places.created_at < b.created_at )
    where  b.created_at is NULL
      and  user_geo_places.category = 'plcs'
```

result:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+
| id                                   | user_id                              | deleted_at | created_at          | updated_at          | latitude                | longitude                | category | status  |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+
| 00019a37-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e20e7777-e788-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.48057242434525200000 | -74.44768883329601000000 | plcs     |       1 |
| 0006162a-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e20e7aef-e772-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.79672692417793640000 | -74.64056815173530000000 | plcs     |       1 |
| 000617f7-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e20ec3c5-e775-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.81266001687632900000 | -74.14159565990940000000 | plcs     |       1 |
| 00061914-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e20edec3-e785-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.26999827965162600000 | -74.92520444926359000000 | plcs     |       1 |
| 00061a1d-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e20eefec-e780-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.81602743809672800000 | -74.30452387342650000000 | plcs     |       1 |
| 00061b21-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e20f3219-e766-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.07453708357600200000 | -74.45911382833413000000 | plcs     |       1 |
| 00061c1e-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e20f7922-e786-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.07195792167629800000 | -74.98244815411275000000 | plcs     |       1 |
| 00061d0e-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e20fd68b-e77e-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.69636703626845700000 | -74.53449074973770000000 | plcs     |       1 |
| 00061e01-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e20fe033-e76b-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.58335267061679900000 | -74.31329113460453000000 | plcs     |       1 |
| 00061ef4-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e2101c1b-e776-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.81639769190586900000 | -74.14211508644942000000 | plcs     |       1 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

explain:

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                 | rows    | Extra                   |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | user_geo_places | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1894347 | Using where             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | b               | ref  | user_id       | user_id | 110     | user_geo_places.user_id             |       1 | Using where; Not exists |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now when I want to get users location by distance

```
Select  user_geo_places.*, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(40.3987545691419)) *
              cos(radians(user_geo_places.latitude)) *
              cos(radians(user_geo_places.longitude)-
              radians(-74.70559604904))+sin(radians(40.3987545691419)) *
              sin(radians(user_geo_places.latitude)))) as distance
    from  user_geo_places
    left join  user_geo_places b
               ON (user_geo_places.user_id = b.user_id
              and  user_geo_places.created_at < b.created_at )
    where  b.created_at is NULL
      and  user_geo_places.category = 'plcs'
    having  distance <= 10
    order by  distance
    limit  10;
```

result:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id                                   | user_id                              | deleted_at | created_at          | updated_at          | latitude                | longitude                 | category | status  | distance            |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| c4d8e37b-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 52616262-e78d-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39875468090060600000 | -74.70637827898038000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.08625581062811027 |
| f4457454-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | cff6b247-e76e-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39847620893127900000 | -74.70646391688517000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.10058008395499662 |
| bc0dbef2-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 29ea9f29-e76a-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39796618688662200000 | -74.70656721545996000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.13839511964323015 |
| c5949373-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 53e7b25c-e778-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39938782472106400000 | -74.70438668849356000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.15080387665201841 |
| c9771f58-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 647afd7e-e76b-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40025693587982800000 | -74.70498255799058000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.18023303176011723 |
| d1d0d5fe-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 83e6d50e-e78c-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39976791050263500000 | -74.70698894253651000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.19049204594530353 |
| c8592196-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 5ef475ae-e789-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39691713303040500000 | -74.70603059763650000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.20985736972660576 |
| b855003d-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 18f63baa-e766-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40058719124699700000 | -74.70495101688891000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.21583472659797534 |
| 0247ffb0-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e534712d-e77b-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40040703062006000000 | -74.70668734489631000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.21964310635910547 |
| ef647fab-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | c981f563-e765-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40036358721588200000 | -74.70425795922452000000 | plcs     |       1 |  0.2319081044464142 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (14.90 sec)
```

Damn. 15 secs? that's very slow for a web query.

explain:

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                 | rows    | Extra                       |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | user_geo_places | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                | 1894347 | Using where; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | b               | ref  | user_id       | user_id | 110     | user_geo_places.user_id             |       1 | Using where; Not exists     |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't want to scan the entire database. I just need the users near 10 kilometers.

```
Select  user_geo_places.*, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(40.3987545691419)) *
         cos(radians(user_geo_places.latitude)) *
         cos(radians(user_geo_places.longitude)-
         radians(-74.70559604904))+sin(radians(40.3987545691419)) *
         sin(radians(user_geo_places.latitude)))) as distance
    from  user_geo_places
    left join  user_geo_places b  ON (user_geo_places.user_id = b.user_id
              and  user_geo_places.created_at < b.created_at
                          )
    where  b.created_at is NULL
      and  user_geo_places.category = 'plcs'
      and  user_geo_places.longitude
         between -74.70559604904 - 10 / abs(cos(radians( 40.3987545691419 )) * 111.045)
             AND -74.70559604904 + 10 / abs(cos(radians( 40.3987545691419 )) * 111.045)
      and  user_geo_places.latitude
         between 40.3987545691419 - ( 10 / 111.045 )
             AND 40.3987545691419 + ( 10 / 111.045 )
    having  distance <= 10
    order by  distance
    limit  10;
```

result:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id                                   | user_id                              | deleted_at | created_at          | updated_at          | latitude               | longitude                | category | status  | distance            |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| c4d8e37b-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 52616262-e78d-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39875468090060600000 | -74.70637827898038000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.08625581062811027 |
| f4457454-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | cff6b247-e76e-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39847620893127900000 | -74.70646391688517000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.10058008395499662 |
| bc0dbef2-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 29ea9f29-e76a-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39796618688662200000 | -74.70656721545996000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.13839511964323015 |
| c5949373-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 53e7b25c-e778-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39938782472106400000 | -74.70438668849356000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.15080387665201841 |
| c9771f58-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 647afd7e-e76b-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40025693587982800000 | -74.70498255799058000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.18023303176011723 |
| d1d0d5fe-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 83e6d50e-e78c-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39976791050263500000 | -74.70698894253651000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.19049204594530353 |
| c8592196-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 5ef475ae-e789-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39691713303040500000 | -74.70603059763650000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.20985736972660576 |
| b855003d-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 18f63baa-e766-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40058719124699700000 | -74.70495101688891000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.21583472659797534 |
| 0247ffb0-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e534712d-e77b-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40040703062006000000 | -74.70668734489631000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.21964310635910547 |
| ef647fab-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | c981f563-e765-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40036358721588200000 | -74.70425795922452000000 | plcs     |       1 |  0.2319081044464142 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (2 min 53.63 sec)
```

Oh come on. really? 2 mins and 53.63 seconds? that is horrible.

explain :

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys      | key      | key_len | ref                                 | rows   | Extra                                              |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | user_geo_places | range | latitude,longitude | latitude | 8       | NULL                                | 683684 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | b               | ref   | user_id            | user_id  | 110     | user_geo_places.user_id             |      1 | Using where; Not exists                            |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Maybe because of the calculations. let's move some of them and set as a 
variable.

```
Set @lon1= -74.70559604904 - 10 / abs(cos(radians( 40.3987545691419 )) * 111.045) ;
Set @lon2= -74.70559604904 + 10 / abs(cos(radians( 40.3987545691419 )) * 111.045) ;
Set @lat1= 40.3987545691419 - ( 10 / 111.045 );
Set @lat2= 40.3987545691419 + ( 10 / 111.045 );
Select
user_geo_places.*,
(6371 * acos(cos(radians(40.3987545691419)) * cos(radians(user_geo_places.latitude)) * cos(radians(user_geo_places.longitude)-radians(-74.70559604904))+sin(radians(40.3987545691419)) * sin(radians(user_geo_places.latitude)))) as distance
from user_geo_places
left join user_geo_places b
on (user_geo_places.user_id = b.user_id and user_geo_places.created_at < b.created_at)
    where  b.created_at is NULL
      and  user_geo_places.category = 'plcs'
      and  user_geo_places.longitude between @lon1 AND @lon2
      and  user_geo_places.latitude  between @lat1 AND @lat2
    having  distance <= 10
    order by  distance
    limit  10;
```

Result:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id                                   | user_id                              | deleted_at | created_at          | updated_at          | latitude               | longitude                | category | status  | distance            |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| c4d8e37b-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 52616262-e78d-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39875468090060600000 | -74.70637827898038000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.08625581062811027 |
| f4457454-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | cff6b247-e76e-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39847620893127900000 | -74.70646391688517000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.10058008395499662 |
| bc0dbef2-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 29ea9f29-e76a-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39796618688662200000 | -74.70656721545996000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.13839511964323015 |
| c5949373-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 53e7b25c-e778-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39938782472106400000 | -74.70438668849356000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.15080387665201841 |
| c9771f58-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 647afd7e-e76b-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40025693587982800000 | -74.70498255799058000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.18023303176011723 |
| d1d0d5fe-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 83e6d50e-e78c-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39976791050263500000 | -74.70698894253651000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.19049204594530353 |
| c8592196-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 5ef475ae-e789-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.39691713303040500000 | -74.70603059763650000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.20985736972660576 |
| b855003d-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | 18f63baa-e766-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40058719124699700000 | -74.70495101688891000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.21583472659797534 |
| 0247ffb0-e790-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | e534712d-e77b-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40040703062006000000 | -74.70668734489631000000 | plcs     |       1 | 0.21964310635910547 |
| ef647fab-e78f-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | c981f563-e765-11e6-8469-5404a66ff99a | NULL       | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 2017-01-31 16:31:48 | 40.40036358721588200000 | -74.70425795922452000000 | plcs     |       1 |  0.2319081044464142 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (2 min 56.29 sec)
```

Man. you are really slow. I don't know what to do with you anymore. time to ask the experts about this.

Currently. I have 1.8 million dummy data stored in my table. My query is still very very slow. This table stores locations by category, so there are other categories for this location. Any good way to fix and improve this?

If I can't fix this. I am planning to move all data by category per table. If things will still be slower because of their past locatins. I might remove that feature, but I really wanted to achieve this. hope anyone could help me

Edit 1:

```
Show Create Table :

+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table           | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_geo_places | CREATE TABLE `user_geo_places` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `latitude` double(25,20) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double(25,20) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
  KEY `longitude` (`longitude`),
  KEY `updated_at` (`updated_at`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+



+--------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                  | Value                |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
| aria_pagecache_age_threshold   | 300                  |
| aria_pagecache_buffer_size     | 134217728            |
| aria_pagecache_division_limit  | 100                  |
| aria_pagecache_file_hash_size  | 512                  |
| binlog_cache_size              | 32768                |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size         | 32768                |
| have_query_cache               | YES                  |
| host_cache_size                | 279                  |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache | OFF                  |
| innodb_ft_cache_size           | 8000000              |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit   | 2000000000           |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size     | 640000000            |
| join_cache_level               | 2                    |
| key_cache_age_threshold        | 300                  |
| key_cache_block_size           | 1024                 |
| key_cache_division_limit       | 100                  |
| key_cache_file_hash_size       | 512                  |
| key_cache_segments             | 0                    |
| max_binlog_cache_size          | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size     | 18446744073709547520 |
| metadata_locks_cache_size      | 1024                 |
| query_cache_limit              | 1048576              |
| query_cache_min_res_unit       | 4096                 |
| query_cache_size               | 1048576              |
| query_cache_strip_comments     | OFF                  |
| query_cache_type               | OFF                  |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate   | OFF                  |
| stored_program_cache           | 256                  |
| table_definition_cache         | 400                  |
| table_open_cache               | 431                  |
| thread_cache_size              | 0                    |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Server specs

- 4 cores
- 8 gb ram
- MariaDB 10.1.20

Engine used : InnoDB

Total Number of Rows : 1,894,326

innodb_buffer_pool_size : 134,217,728

Currently 98% percent of the records are all in new york

Runned SQL_NO_CACHE

```
Select SQL_NO_CACHE
    user_geo_places.*
from user_geo_places
left join user_geo_places b
on (user_geo_places.user_id = b.user_id and user_geo_places.created_at < b.created_at)
where b.created_at is NULL and user_geo_places.category = 'plcs'
limit 10

10 rows in set (0.00 - 0.07 sec)
```

By the way, the column status is useless and will be drop

Comment: what is your mysql version ?

Comment: How many rows in the tables?

Comment: [_UUIDs_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiduuid-performance/) and [_lat/lng_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/latitudelongitude-indexing/) are difficult to optimize.  Read those links to see if some of the tips will help.  Then, I will consider digging deeper.

Comment: `(0.00 sec)` may be bogus -- Was the Query cache turned on?  Run timing tests with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`

Comment: One-third of the table is in NYC, no wonder 20 km was not tight enough.

Answer (score 0):

Shrinking the table would help *some*.

- `double(25,20)` takes 12 bytes and has a precision somewhere around the width of molecules.
- `UUIDs` can be packed into `BINARY(16)` (16 bytes) instead of `VARCHAR(36)` (37 bytes).
- It might be useful to normalize `category` into a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.
- `INT` is always 4 bytes; use a 1-byte `TINYINT` for flags such as `status`.

Without `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, we cannot see the indexes, particularly whether you have single-column indexes or composite indexes.

- Latest by category might benefit from `INDEX(category, created_at)`
- 'Nearby' and 'order by distance' are especially difficult; see [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/latitudelongitude-indexing/) .

It is often useful to split "current state" and "history" into two tables.  The former has only one row per entity; the latter has (potentially) many.  This greatly simplifies queries involving "latest".  This may also allow you to get rid of `status` by removing a dead entry from "current state" while leaving it in "history".  Filtering on `status` *may* (currently) be another performance killer in the queries.

It looks like the `UUIDs` are "type 1"; in addition to shrinking them, their bits can be rearranged to make them chronologically ordered.  They will improve performance of *some* queries by improving the 'locality of reference'.  See [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiduuid-performance/) .

What engine does the table use?  How big is the cache for that engine?  How much RAM do you have?

The `LEFT JOIN` needs `INDEX(user_id, created_at)`.  (Of course, if you separate the history out, this will not longer be relevant.)

What percent of the table is the "current state"?

I have presented several suggestions; it is hard to say which will be the most beneficial.

Why did running with the bounding box run so slow?  It seems to be a combination of things:

- 20km in NYC covers a lot of territory.  And perhaps 1/3 of the table??
- The Optimizer does not always "get it right" when deciding between using an index and simply scanning the table.  The latter would have been faster *this* time.
- The may be some caching issues.

Comment: Hi Rick, Thank you for your time. I have updated my question. looks like I have a lot of mistakes. I've been storing location of each fleas in a dog, i'll change this to DECIMAL(6,4) and will be using auto increment for id.

Comment: By the way. how do I identify if there are any caching issues?

Comment: Cache...  How much RAM, which engine, how big is the table, is the Query cache on?